# Mongoose not saving changes to a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sorry if this might be a duplicate question but I'm quite having a hard time understanding Mongoose. 
 I am working on a Node.js project that implements Mongoose and MongoDB. What I want to accomplish is to modify and save some users' data through a call from a specific endpoint. 
Mongoose Schema looks like this

```
  var UserSchema = new Schema({
  isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  nickname: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, trim: true, unique: true, dropDubs: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  salt: { type: String },
  verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  bio: {
    type: { type: String, enum: [0,1] }, // 0='Appassionato', 1='Giocatore'
    birthday: String,
    height: Number,
    number: Number,
    role: { type: String, enum: [0,1,2,3] }, // 0='Playmaker', 1='Ala', 2='Guardia', 3='Centro'
    team: String,
    city: String,
    aboutMe: String,
  },
  newsletter: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  lastCheckin: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Checkin'},
  follows: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Structure'}],
  score: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  profilePicture: String,
  lastLogin: {type: Date},
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    accessToken: String,
    profileImage : String
  }
}, {
  collection: 'users',
  retainKeyOrder: true,
  timestamps: true,
}).plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

Following is the code for when the endpoint gets interrogated

```
exports.updateUser = (req,res)  => {
  var userId = req.params.userId;
  var updates = req.body;

  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {$set: updates}, (err, saved) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Ritorno questo: " + saved);
      return res.status(202).json(saved);
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json(saved);
    }
  });

};
```

As far as I understood, the method findOneAndUpdate exposed by Mongoose should find the document I'm looking for and then modify it and save it. This doesn't happen though. 
Through PostMan I'm sending this JSON

```
{"bio.aboutMe":"Hello this is just a brief description about me"}
```

But PostMan is responding with the non-modified object. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try this :  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {$set: updates}, {new:true} ...

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue! What does {new:true} do?

Comment: it returns the updated document :) https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Comment: Oh ok, because even if I tried to query the database later it didn't show the new changes. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to add {new:true}, it give you back the updated document. 
In the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) :

> If we do need the document returned in our application there is
>   another, often better, option:

```
> Tank.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, { new: true },
> function (err, tank) {   if (err) return handleError(err);  
> res.send(tank); });
```

This is something I don't really like as there is another option if we don't want to have the document → update

So what you need to do is :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {$set: updates}, {new:true}.....
```